# How to hide the titlebar in Opera?

Tags: opera

I just did a fresh installation of Ubuntu 10.10 64-bits on my notebook. Downloaded the Opera 10.63 .deb package (http://www.opera.com/browser/download/) and installed it.

Now I want to know if there's a way to remove the titlebar to make the browser look like the windows version.

Comment: Why not just use Chrome? It is much better!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Compiz for visual effects, you have an option.

If you do not already have the CompizConfig Settings Manager you can install it by `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`.

- Warning: [What are some of the issues with CCSM and why would I want to avoid it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it)

Under the CompizConfig Settings Manager:

1. Click on Window Decoration
2. Type in the blank next to Decoration windows: `(any)&!(name=opera)`

Now all windows will have a window decoration besides Opera.  However, you lose the ability of dragging to resize or to move the window.  You will have to use keystrokes for it (ie. holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> to move the window)

Comment: Yeah It worked exactly as you said! The problem of losing the ability of dragging to resize or move the window is not a problem at all I just have to remember to use the <ALT> as you said!

Comment: You can drag and resize with the titlebar? Hmm, interesting, but not quite as useful as using modifier keys and the mouse or things similar to compiz's grid and put plugins.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't offer the window buttons beside the tab bar like the Windows version does, but thanks for the tip regardless.

Answer (score 4):

Right-click on the tab panel -> show border

Answer (score 1):

For those using KDE...

Right-click on the window title bar, select "Advanced >> No Border". If you want this to be permanent, then right-click on the window title bar, select "Advanced >> Special Window Settings...", then select the preferences tab, then tick the "No border option", then select "Force" from the drop-down menu.