# Gnome Shell running applications in Unity?

Tags: 11.10, unity, gnome

GNOME shell have current running windows mode like in Mac and I love it, but I don't wont use GNOME Shell, may be have some way to display the current running applications as well and in Unity.

**Update:**

[I want this in Unity :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/petfa.png)

Comment: Sorry, but, what is current running windows mode?. Maybe the result of hitting SHIFT+ALT+UP is what you are looking for?.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific/descriptive of what you are referring to? Do you mean what comes up when you hit alt+tab? P.S. Unity runs on top of GNOME 3 in 11.10. GNOME Shell and Unity are *just* shells for GNOME 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install [Compizconfig Settings Manager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager).

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

- Warning: [What are some of the issues with CCSM and why would I want to avoid it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it)

Then, run compizconfig Settings Manager and go to Window Management -> Scale plugin. Now, under the third tab - Bindings, you can configure the window picker you want with any corner of your desktop. If I understood you correctly, you would need to click on the fourth entry, "initiate window picker for all windows" and choose the Top-Left corner.

[image]