# Where is the 3D windows setting for the cube in compiz open GL for gnome 3.2 (ubuntu classic) configuration manager?

Tags: 11.10, compiz, opengl, effects, gnome-classic

Incredibly useful when working with a lot windows open but missing on CompizConfig Setting Manager in 11.10 x86 Desktop version.

I was copying my settings from my big 10.04 64bit workstation, but the 3D Windows checkbox on the 10.04 workstation is not found on the 11.10 32bit workstation.

The screenshot of "OpenGL window and composting manage" in Ubuntu Software Center displays the 3D windows prominently.

What's happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a *3D Windows* plugin available in the *Effects* section of CCSM if you install the extras module for Compiz

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra
```

Warning 1 - this cannot be used in conjunction with Unity - so if you intend to flip into the Unity session you'll need to turn off 3D windows first.

Warning 2 - please see this [question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it) as to why using `ccsm` can cause  serious stability issues.

Comment: Right on ⋯ curious though why Ubuntu heads would put pix of 3D Windows on Ubuntu Software Center's Compiz page.  & thanks for the Unity warning ⋯ I only use Unity on my cheap laptop, not on a real working computer.