# Problem with Radeon HD 6870 on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, radeon

Hello I got the Radeon HD 6870 on my new computer and I install Ubuntu 11.10, the problem is that when I installed the AMD Catalyst 11.11 and I play a 1080p video isn't as smooth as I hope to be, (it's hard to explain) it's like if the video was a little bit slow, and it's **annoying**.

So I uninstall the drivers and the video looks very good (as smooth as my PS3 for example) but the colors are horrible and the resolution sucks, it's 1080p the same as my TV but it look like it was bigger so I can't see half of the bar on the left side and I can't see the bar in the up side of my desktop.
My question is: what drivers do you recommend me to install, and if you recommend me the Catalyst, do you know a configuration for a smoother video???

Thanks.

Comment: Stick to the community-supported `radeon` driver...

Answer (score 2):

Catalyst may be the best driver for your card.

This should help "smooth" the video:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Run CompizConfig Settings Manager.

Click the OpenGL icon, then deselect the "Sync to VBlank" option.

> ### Warning
>
> This answer recommends the use of CompizConfig Settings Manager (`ccsm`). This is an advanced tool which has been known to
> [sometimes break users' desktops](https://askubuntu.com/q/80589/18612), even through ordinary use or
> changing options which seem innocent enough. You are taking a risk by
> following this answer or any advice recommending the use of CCSM. If
> you do encounter problems, please see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/17610/18612) for
> instructions on how to restore Unity.

Answer (score 0):

Few players support vaapi, vlc does when you enable GPU acceleration for codecs and install xvba-va driver. This will give you smooth vids.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the latest Catalyst driver, which must be 12.1 or later.

Comment: **crackout12:** Even better, please expand this answer to include information (or at least links) about specifically how to obtain and install the latest Catalyst driver. **@Mitch** This really is an answer, or a "half answer" as this is sometimes called. Such posts can sometimes be deleted, but [they should *not* be comments instead of answers](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2281/please-stop-posting-half-answers-and-dumb-advice-as-comments).