# Toggle horizontal, vertical and full window maximization within Unity?

Tags: unity, window-manager, window

I want to toggle windows between:

```
horizontal maximized <-> horizontal unmaximized ALT+F7
vetical maximized <-> vertical unmaximized ALT+F6
(both) maximized <-> (both) unmaximized ALT+F5
```

I looked into ccsm but the maximization plugin doesn't work this way or I didn't figured it out.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "horizontal maximized"?  A window is either maximized or not...

Comment: horizontal maximizes only in x-direction, vertical only in y-direction. Where as normal maximization maximizes in both: x- and y-direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

In the *General Compiz Options - Keybindings* are the toggle options you require.

Note - <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> & <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> are generally bound to other functions -

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> are good substitutes....

**Warning: [What are some of the issues with CCSM and why would I want to avoid it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it)**

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've been looking for, except in general options :)

Comment: Unfortunately the settings for toggling Horizontal/Vertical no longer seem to exist in 14.04. At least you can still maximize in each dimension, then Unmaximize using a different shortcut.

Comment: These settings no longer exist, but FYI there is a perfect, fully working solution. See Hal Canary's answer (currently bottom of page)

Answer (score 1):

It's not toggle but you can set horizontal/vertical maximization shortcuts in the `System settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Windows`

Comment: Great, at least maximizing both directions is togglable, and horizontal maximization works in one way, and you can disable it when maximize and unmaximize afterwards. A bit complicated but best what I've found so far. I searched within ccsm but with no luck.

Comment: This works in 13.10 too, but I'm still looking for a full-toggle solution without CCSM.

Comment: I've remapped `ctrl-super-up` to _Maximize vertically_, but it's still doing a full maximize :-/

Comment: There is a solution that also toggles. See Hal Canary's answer (currently bottom of page.)

Answer (score 1):

```
dconf write \
  /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/toggle-window-maximized-vertically-key \
  "'<Alt>F6'"
dconf write \
  /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/toggle-window-maximized-horizontally-key \
  "'<Alt>F7'"
```