# CCSM Missing from Unity

Tags: 11.10, unity, ccsm

After using CCSM 4 or 5 weeks ago to adjust the launcher icons to minimum setting I have been spending all my time in Gnome Shell. I have made a number of adjustments in Shell (tweak tool etc)  Today I loaded Unity to make some adjustments via CCSM but found that it was missing altogether - ie Would not load when entered in search box.
CCSM also does not show up in Synpatic. Unity is working O.K. with no other problems.

Could somebody explain where CCSM has gone and how to restore?

Thank you.

Comment: reinstall it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing it through command line. 
Type this into the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager python-compizconfig compiz-fusion-plugins-extra compiz-fusion-bcop compiz-fusion-plugins-main compizconfig-backend-gconf
```

That's all one line and when prompted with [sudo] password type in your own password.
Hope that helps.

- [What are some of the issues with CCSM and why would I want to avoid it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it)