# CCSM broke my Unity 3D on 11.10

Tags: unity, compiz

Ok. 
I wanted to see how 3D cube would look like with my 11.10, so I installed CCSM and turned on 3D cube and disabled expose (think that is what it is called). Then after that everything went sideways. I can get to the desktop but only see part of the top panel, no launcher, no indication area, just 'file' 'edit' 'view'...'help' alt+F2 does not work, the super key does not bring up the dash. Unity 2D works, but I rather Unity 3D. CCSM in 2D did not help. What can I do to restore Unity to before my fiddling with it? I tired ctrl+alt+F1 (to try some thing in terminal I saw for an answer to a question similar to mine) at the log in but i just got a black screen that was not responsive.

Thank you for your time and answers.

Comment: Try some of the solutions listed in this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it and then edit your question if it doesn't work, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctrl+Alt+T should open the terminal. If that doesn't work, try logging in to Unity 2D (option from clicking on the cog at the login screen). From there run:

unity --reset

and failing that, try:

unity --replace

to completely restore Unity. (note: it doesn't show up well in my browser, but both the above codes had two consecutive dashes)

If you can live without the flashy graphics/interface and want a stable system then avoid CCSM like the plague until they sort it out. It seems to be causing nothing but trouble.

I literally just overcame this problem, not sure how long it will last though. Do your googling and you will find the solution - this page helped me:

http://sqizit.bartletts.id.au/2011/11/07/unity-launchersidebar-missing-on-ubuntu-11-10/

Best of luck.

Will

Comment: Thank you. will try this soon as I can, and will pretty sure by the looks of it will be accepting this once I can try it out.

Comment: amazing worked like a charm, thanks for the details and your time.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using the following command in your terminal window:

*unity --reset*

Here is additional info:

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-reset-unity-launcher-icons-or.html

Good luck.

Comment: But how can I run terminal? I cannot activate the dash or see the launcher?

Answer (score 0):

CCSM has been known to completely hose Unity/Compiz settings. It's relatively easy to recover from this.

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/127310/75166), has worked for me:

Just backup (rename) `~/.compiz-1` and `~/.config/compiz-1` directories and let them to be created again with the default settings. You'll then need to logout and log back in again.

```
mv ~/.compiz-1 ~/.compiz-1.BACKUP
mv ~/.config/compiz-1 ~/.config/compiz-1.BACKUP
```