# Keyboard and mouse not working after upgrade

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, keyboard, mouse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

I just upgraded to 12.04.  Now, I can get into the desktop but after that point nothing works including keyboard and mouse. Therefore I am unable to use terminal.  What do I do to get it working again?

Comment: Hello, this question is vague and given nothing works I don't think it will be easy to diagnose and resolve. It may be easiest to just recover your data and reinstall: http://askubuntu.com/questions/126724/my-system-is-totally-messed-up-what-is-the-best-course-of-action

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

If previous to the upgrade you had messed with compiz settings, I guess I (and many other people) have been into the same issue. Solve it by [resetting compiz settings to defaults](https://askubuntu.com/a/127310/33305).

I have an ATI Radeon HD5750, but I guess people with nVidia cards have also experienced the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using another USB keyboard, as your existing keyboard may be the cause of problem. if even that does not work for you, re-install a fresh copy of 12.04 rather than upgrading.

Kindly describe specific problem you are facing. The more details you provide the more help you will get.