# Launcher, top Panel, and window decorations missing after 12.04 upgrade

Tags: unity, launcher, gui

I upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04 and now my launcher is missing. I opened terminal using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and the menu shows but the GUI (bar) window decorations above that is missing.
[image]
Things like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> and image previewer don't work. I've tried whats mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127240/missing-launcher-after-12-04-upgrade) but no luck.

Another Screenshot of my GUI looks :
[image]

Comment: I don't think we ought to close this question, but I do recommend you [report this as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got this resolved. Apparently the upgrade process wasn't through 100%.

I did the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And somehow after a restart it *magically* worked.

Answer (score 12):

First, try `sudo apt-get -f install && sudo apt-get --reinstall install unity`

Then, try `unity --reset`, followed by `unity --replace`; try doing this from the desktop and also from the console (switch via `Ctrl-Alt-F1`).

Comment: of no help still missing launcher + menu bar

Comment: Thank you so much. I spent over an hour trying to get this stuff to show back up and this was the only thing that worked out of countless SO suggestions.

Answer (score 11):

Try executing this command in the terminal:

```
unity --reset
```

It resets your Unity.

Comment: I did try that. No change.

Comment: shows "deprecated" on ubuntu 13.04. Yes I know the question is about 12.04 :)

Answer (score 6):

I think you are missing the indicators. Open a terminal window and type in the following to add the required packages:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-appmenu indicator-applet-session
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-complete
sudo apt-get install indicator-application indicator-session 
sudo apt-get install indicator-power indicator-sound
```

I had installed a minimal Unity desktop on an Ubuntu Server image but that minimal desktop didn't have any of the top panel buttons for sound, shutdown etc.

Adding the above indicators restored everything after a logout or restart of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem for weeks and had tried the above recommendations. I was due to reload my box when I stumbled upon changing the resolution. My native resolution was 1920x1080 (16:9). I was launching firefox from terminal window and needed to double the resolution for a presentation I was watching. **I changed to 1280:720 (16:9) and was surprised to see the left menu return.** When I went back to 1920x1080 it was there again too.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the problem because of I installed the `ia32-libs` package yesterday (finding it wasted me a long long time)!

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

After I executed the above command.

If you get the error message:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

You may encounter the same problem with me. You can solve it by this way:

1. Get the path of the 64bit `libGL.so.1` by command `locate libGL.so.1`. For example, my path was `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1`.
2. Add the path exclude the file name (`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa`) to `/etc/ld.do.conf`. Just start a new line.
3. Execute the command `sudo ldconfig`
4. Restart, and good luck.

PS: I'm Chinese and my English is very poor, so some words or sentences may make you confused. Sorry to all. I like this forum; I can get lots of assistance here. Thanks for your sharing and kindness.

Comment: your English is perfectly okay :)

Answer (score 1):

I have used gnome (classic). After update to 12.04 any window or app window did not had task-bar with min/max buttons. I have logged off, on log off screen clicked on gnome/ubuntu sign and chose ubuntu and logged in and windows are backed to normal. Logged off again and switch to gnome (not gnome classic) and windows are normal.

Comment: This isn't an answer.  It should be posted in comments.

Comment: @CallmeV, read it twice, he tells how he got it solved for himself :-)

Comment: @guntbert It doesn't fix gnome-classic so imo it's not an answer.  If this is an answer the answer is use a different DE, which isn't an answer.

Comment: UPDATE: Ok,I tried today both "gnome" from menu and the both are fine.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem too. I found that I had some packages that were kept back.
I did an `apt-get install` on all these packages and now things work again.

Comment: Running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` will also usually upgrade any packages that have been kept back.

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of fglrx with `sudo apt-get autoremove fglrx --purge` and rebooted `sudo shutdown -r now`.

Answer (score 0):

I had pretty much the same problem under 12.04. Unity was slow with my aged GPU, so I was using Unity 2d as my desktop for months. For no apparent reason, it suddenly refused to display launchpad and title bar (for all users). Reenabling Unity in CCSM as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128676/launcher-and-window-menu-bar-missing-after-12-04-upgrade/267210#267210) was part of the solution, but none of the other measures suggested here, there or in several other related threads, including, but not limited to:

- Reinstalling unity
- Reinstalling ubuntu desktop
- Removing all relevant (e.g. compiz, gconf, etc.) configuration
  information

helped me to completely resolve these symptoms under 12.04 (64 bit).

```
unity --reset
```

would not work for me. After delivering a variety of error and information messages, it would always hang at:

```
Setting Update "run_key"
```

as shown in the log posted in [the thread titled "unity has vanished"](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1974219) for unity run with no arguments.

I noticed that the error message delivered by:

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

was similar to some of the errors reported by unity --reset:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

as reported by user139869 above.  Unfortunately, his solution did not work for me.
After extensive searching, I found the following solution:

1. Get the path of libGL.so.1 by using the command locate libGL.so.1.
2. Add a link to the library in /usr/lib/ as shown in the following
   example:
3. sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib

   (courtesy of [J.D. Bartlett](http://sqizit.bartletts.id.au/2011/11/07/unity-launchersidebar-missing-on-ubuntu-11-10/))
4. Restart the computer.

This not only allowed both unity_support_test-p and unity --reset to run, it also allowed Unity 2d to start. I have no idea what caused my problems, but since creating the links above (several weeks now) I have had no further problems.

Answer (score -5):

Go to monitor Preferences: 
Select same image in all monitors

Comment: How is that an answer to the question? He said nothing about multi-monitor.