# Nvidia driver break unity, gnome anything - even after uninstall

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 13.04

So I'm having this issue,
I'm using a i7 laptop with an Intel graphics card, and a Nvidia hdmi card for external displays.

The cursor flickers and sometimes dissapears when I have my external monitor plugged in, the external monitor works, but it lags my cursor.

I tried installing the Nvidia-current driver and this broke everything, the menus and bars are missing.

When uninstalling the nvidia driver, it's still in the same state.

Can anyone purpose something?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with AMD Radeon card. I tried all the solutions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128676/launcher-and-window-menu-bar-missing-after-12-04-upgrade) but non of them worked for me, try them and see if they could solve your problem.