# Application launcher is missing

Tags: launcher

I have 13.04 installed from a DVD that I got on eBay but the application launcher is missing. I've tried CCSM but it won't work!

Answer (score 3):

If you can't download the CD, you could buy from the Canonical Shop here: http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=976

We don't offer support to variations of Ubuntu, forks, unofficial variants and derivatives are not controlled or guided by Canonical Ltd. ([list on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions#Third-party_distributions)) and generally have different goals in mind. You should **ALWAYS download/buy Ubuntu from trusted sources, preferable directly from the makers**. You should verify your CD, so it won't include defects or modifications.

1. Insert your Ubuntu CD into the drive of the computer that you want
   to run/install Ubuntu onto.
2. Turn the computer on, or restart the computer.
3. While booting from the CD, hold any key to access the CD menu.
4. At the CD menu, choose 'Check CD for Defects' (if you never get to
   the menu, try BootFromCD)

You can also order CD's from a third party at http://www.osdisc.com/cgi-bin/view.cgi/products/linux/ubuntu

Comment: @EliahKagan actually, the OP ask "why the launcher is not showing?" but since he included that he got his copy of Ubuntu from eBay (ie, we don't know what could be modified there), most of us were concerned if he got "Ubuntu" or a "bad copy of Ubuntu that will cause problems like happens with Windows". Since we don't know what could be modified, since the launcher didn't show up in the LiveDVD (or so I would like to think) we recommend to verify the disk, then from there start the troubleshooting. Once we know what we are dealing with, it would be easier to solve OP's problem.

Comment: @EliahKagan I ripped off the wikipedia article now ;)

Comment: Why do you have to talk about unofficial derivatives at all? Do you think the OP is using one? It seems to me that the concern is that the copy may be corrupted--a bad or damaged burn--not that the copy is an unofficial derivative. What do unofficial derivatives have to do with the advice to always download/buy installation media for official Ubuntu OSes from official sources?

Answer (score 2):

You can download Ubuntu for FREE from the Ubuntu website, all you need to do is write it to a CD/DVD or USB drive and you have it for free for ever! [Go here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Comment: It is possible that the OP does not have a fast enough internet to download an ISO file.  I had this problem when I started using Ubuntu 11.04, only dialup was available in my area so I did exactly what the OP did, I bought a disk on Ebay for $5 or so that had Ubuntu burnt on it by the seller.  So while your answer is valid, it may not be feasible for the OP. I luckily have since been able to get faster internet but I would recommend Ebay as the cheapest alternative if you are unable to download Ubuntu yourself.  Not trying to nitpick here just point out an uncommon issue....

Comment: BTW I gave your answer a +1 but with the caveat in my previous comment. ;)  note: that on further checking on the link you provided, 12.04 is out of stock and 13.04 is not offered in the store at the moment. Still not a bad answer so I will not change my vote, just and F.Y.I.

Comment: I guessed that this may be the case, but I didn't want to see someone being ripped off and spending a wad of money on something that is available for free :) Thanks for the +1

Answer (score 2):

[Ubuntu Hashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes) website has the file verification hashes of all of the Ubuntu releases. Install GtkHash and check your 13.04 disk (or whatever it is) file verification hash to see if you bought a bad 13.04 disk on eBay.

Answer (score 1):

It is highly recommended to either buy direct or download iso from ubuntu.com.  You could compare checksums from ubuntu site with your dvd to verify files.

Have you tried searching Ask Ubuntu?  The search function is very handy tool with many filters.  Using search to look for the term "missing launcher" gives these search [results](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=launcher%20missing) clicking on the votes filter resorts results into a list where the most amount of users have found useful answers to same term.  Like these [results](https://askubuntu.com/search?tab=votes&q=launcher%20missing)

Look at this Ask Ubuntu q+a [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128676/launcher-and-window-menu-bar-missing-after-12-04-upgrade) which highlights the need to reset Unity (the thing that takes care of many features of Ubuntu Desktop) and update and upgrade. Looking at this q+a [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/17381/102029) which will give even more options on how to fix.

As this is a fresh install i would personally recommend updating upgrading before rebooting to see what results are before trying the reset unity options.

Hope this helps with getting acquainted with Ask Ubuntu and welcome.  Please update your question if there is any more trouble getting going with your new Ubuntu install.