# Application Launcher on 13.04 missing

Tags: 13.04, launcher

I ordered 13.04 on eBay, but when I installed it the application launcher was missing. I could only open applications from the terminal.
I installed CCSM, but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/330882/application-launcher-is-missing/330921#330921 ?