# Everytime I enter to ubuntu I don't have bars, I dont have browser, etc

Tags: 12.04, unity

Every time I enter on Ubuntu, this happens:

[image]

Then when I put my mouse in the corner it would give me a black image

I have my unity enabled but it doesn't give me a little box next to it to enable it(but I think I have it enabled because when I click on it in the left it says to enable it and I have it enabled)

[image]

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launcher and window menu bar missing after 12.04 upgrade](http://askubuntu.com/questions/128676/launcher-and-window-menu-bar-missing-after-12-04-upgrade), or http://askubuntu.com/questions/286088/menu-bar-and-launcher-missing-in-ubuntu-13-04, or http://askubuntu.com/questions/127240/missing-launcher-after-12-04-upgrade Please check these links and see if any of those answers work

Comment: If you have another image to add to the details of your question, you can post the link as a comment to your question and someone with higher rep might add it to the body of your question.