# Fan speed high since upgrade to 12.04

Tags: cpu, fan, noise

Since I have updated to 12.04 LTS my desktop pc's fan runs permanently with high speed and is annoyingly noisy. CPU temperature is low.
Here is what the sensors command gets me:

```
nouveau-pci-0400
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +48.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +115.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +39.0°C  (high = +82.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:       +40.0°C  (high = +82.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:       +37.0°C  (high = +82.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:       +44.0°C  (high = +82.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

f8000-isa-0a00
Adapter: ISA adapter
+3.3V:        +3.34 V  
3VSB:         +3.38 V  
Vbat:         +3.23 V  
fan1:        1675 RPM
fan2:         959 RPM
fan3:           0 RPM  ALARM
fan4:           0 RPM
temp1:        +42.0°C  (high = +70.0°C, hyst = +60.0°C)
temp2:        +25.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, hyst = +85.0°C)
temp3:        +24.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, hyst = +85.0°C)
```

Same issue of noisy fan has been noted in Dell 1555 after upgrade to 12.04 with output of sensors command as below:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +51.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)
temp2:        +59.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)
temp3:        +79.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)

radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +80.0°C
```

Is there a way to figure out which application is causing it?

Comment: Have you checked [top](http://www.unixtop.org/man.shtml) and/or [powertop](http://linux.die.net/man/1/powertop) to check which application is producing such a heavy load?

Answer (score 2):

Same here, and solved with jupiter. It seems there's nothing you can do with that, so the best is keep them low via software when you don't need much power.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this http://kastang.com/blog/2009/08/manually-change-ati-fan-speed-in-ubunt/

I tested on my 7950 and it works fine (put 0% is ok)

The main part is:

> To check the temperature of your card: aticonfig --adapter=0
>   --od-gettemperature
>
> To change the fan speed: aticonfig --pplib-cmd "set fanspeed 0 XX"
>
> (Where the XX is replace it with the fan speed percentage)

I also found that compiz cpu was high -> tried this: https://askubuntu.com/a/127310/26508 and it works too.

I reproduce the main part here:

> Just backup (rename) ~/.compiz-1 and ~/.config/compiz-1 directories
>   and let them to be created again with the default settings (you'll
>   need to logout and log back in again).
>
> mv ~/.compiz-1 ~/.compiz-1.BACKUP
>
> mv ~/.config/compiz-1 ~/.config/compiz-1.BACKUP
>
> After having restarted and confirmed that
>   everything works as expected, you can simply remove these backups
>   (unless you have a use for them).

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question it would be preferable to include the information here and leave the links as references.

Comment: @MarkPaskal totally agree - done