# Compiz taking 40-30% of CPU resources, is it ok ?

Tags: compiz, performance

On normal working with nothing opened,  `compiz` fires up to 50% CPU usage on my machine. Which is abnormal I think.

Is this a bug or is this behavior ok?

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on Intel i5 processor
ATI 5400 mobility 512 MB Graphic card

Comment: Can you provide the output of `glxinfo | grep render`?

Comment: direct rendering: Yes
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5000 Series
    GL_KTX_buffer_region, GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_conditional_render,

Comment: There a quite a few reports on this, e.g. [bug #803943](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/803943) and more...

Comment: nope, it is not at all okay

Comment: Ok, so your graphics chipset is recognised and video driver is loaded, one possible reason could be if the software renderer is used, then compiz might cause high CPU usage. But clearly that is not the case here.

Comment: I have AMD card, whenever I use xorg driver instead of ati driver I see that compiz takes a high percentage of CPU and laptop starts heating or the fan becomes noisy. As soon as I install the ati driver everything goes back to normal

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. Compiz constantly at around 40% (AMD CPU, ATI 58xx, 12.04). Then i followed this post https://askubuntu.com/a/127310/26508 and CPU utilization dropped below 10%. Hope it helps.