# Dock bar, maximize, and minimize buttons disappeared after doing a "reset to defaults" in CCSM

Tags: 12.04, compiz, lts

Recently i installed compiz configuration manager after that i went to unity under that and clicked "reset to defaults". This caused the dock bar to disappear and also close maximize and minimize buttons have dissapeared for all windows.I am running ubuntu 12.04 LTS. It will be really helpful if some one can help me solve this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CCSM broke my Unity 3D on 11.10](http://askubuntu.com/q/92079/37006)

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to access a command line only session, login with your usual username and password, and run the command `unity --reset` to reset all your Unity related settings. You can then get back to the usual graphical session by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>.

Comment: I have followed the above steps but still the issue persists.