# Why isn't Unredirect Fullscreen Windows enabled by default?

Tags: compiz, performance, 3d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does ‘Unredirect fullscreen Windows’ option in compiz improve performance for video playback?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99228/does-unredirect-fullscreen-windows-option-in-compiz-improve-performance-for-vi)

I'm a developer and even I had to use Google to find out what is wrong with my 3D performance. It's ridiculous that a new user should know about CCSM and the Unredirect Fullscreen Windows setting. Why it isn't enabled by default?

Anyway, I'm still happy now that I've found that setting.

Comment: This will probably be closed as a dupe but I should point out it's a [high-importance bug in Launchpad just assigned last week](https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz/+bug/1063690). Bugs are off topic here so it would still need closing. Thanks for pointing this item out though, I'll try it. (also don't worry about the question being closed, we close questions all the time).