# Cannot resize launcher icons in Unity

Tags: 11.10, unity, compiz, launcher, ubuntu-tweak

I am using Oneiric. I have Unity 4.28 installed. I have also installed CCSM, Ubuntu Tweak, Dconf tools and MyUnity. I have tried resizing the launcher icons using these tools, but none of them are having the desired effect.

It would help if any one could provide suggestions on how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open **CompizConfig Settings Manager**. Go to **Ubuntu Unity Plugin** and go to tab **Experimental**.
**Launcher icon size** is the option you need.

Comment: [Please note that ccsm may harm to your system](http://askubuntu.com/q/80589/3940). We actively discourage people to install and run it.

Comment: Indeed the CCSM can harm your system, but this is a way to change the size of the icons. You can always uninstall it later.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because you're in a unity-2d session. Open a terminal, copy & paste this command in, press enter. Unity (3d) will return `ubuntu`, unity-2d will mean just that

```
echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
```

unity-2d doesn't support launcher resize yet, it's possible but that's another question.

Answer (score 0):

Well this worked for me in 12.04. I have to use Unity-2D on my old laptop.

http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-unity-2d-resize-launcher.html