# Change curser location to bring up Unity launcher

Tags: unity, launcher

I want the launcher to show when I move the cursor to the top-left corner instead of the left edge because the way it is it tends to show when I don't want it to. How can I do that_

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For 11.10 and earlier**

To adjust the reveal mode of the Launcher, you can use [compizconfig-settings-manager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager]. You can install CCSM by running the following command in a terminal:

`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

- [What are some of the issues with CCSM and why would I want to avoid it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it)

After installing CCSM, open it and click on 'Ubuntu Unity Plugin'.

[image]

Click on the option and click on the option for 'Reveal mode'. There, you can choose which part of the screen should trigger the launcher.

[image]

**For 12.04**

There is a much easier way to change the reveal mode of the launcher in 12.04.

To do that, you can right click on the desktop and click 'Change Desktop Background' option.

[image]

After that, in the 'User Interface' application that appears, move to 'Behaviour' tab. There, you can change the 'Reveal spot' of the launcher.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I played with the reveal settings, top-left not seeming to work very well, until ccsm told me about a conflict with the Desktop Wall plugin. I chose not to change anything and reset the reveal mode back to default. But now I have an issue with the close, max, min buttons on the windows. If the windows are not maxed and I move the cursor over the buttons, they are not highlighted anymore :-( Will stop using ccsm. MyUnity is quite basic though...

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Hope you can get it fixed soon. :)

Answer (score 0):

Right now you can't do this in Unity on Ubuntu 11.10 You can try out GNOME 3, or test the amazingly stable 12.04 beta, in which they have implemented in Unity 5.2, or you can install the Unity team's PPA and use the beta version of Unity. 11.04 also had this feature. But if you want to keep your Unity version, Ubuntu version, and desktop environment, you'll have to wait for 12.04. Sorry.