# Turning on desktop cube removes task bars

Tags: compiz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some of the issues with ccsm and why should I not use it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it)

I am knew to Ubuntu and I tried to go about customizing mine with the desktop cube and all that with the wobble windows. The wobble windows I had know problem with, then I tried to change the Desktop Wall to the Desktop Cube and it removed both of my task bar. All I had left was two other window I had up (Ubuntu Software, Home Folder). CompizConfig Settings Manger disappeared after I tried to change it back. I had to press (cont-alt-delete) and get in to the guest addition and erase the user and make another one because my dash bar was unaccessable.

Comment: Installed ubuntu in virtualbox?

Answer (score 2):

Compiz-config-settings manger is very dangerous in unity
if it crashed your system

press alt+ctrl+f2
and enter username and password
Then type

```
unity --reset
```

- [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)
- [What are some of the issues with CCSM and why would I want to avoid it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it)

Answer (score 0):

one thing i ve learned to do right off.Open the dash and type terminal.when it comes up drag the terminal to the desktop that way when you lose your bars you have direct access to terminal.In ccsm I have started unchecking the unity plugin box then checking the effects I want.After I have checked the effects I want I then proceed to recheck the unity plugin box.On desktop cube when i rechecked the unity box I clicked disable wall,resolve conflicts and lastly disable left flip.Since I have been doing this way I have had no issues whatsoever on several desktops enabling the desktop cube.