# Menus disappear on changing compiz settings

Tags: unity, 12.04, compiz

I installed compizconfig on ubuntu 12.04, and was changing the desktop effects, suddenly all menus disappeared, I can't even open terminal. I restarted several times. When I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, logged in and typed `unity --reset`, it displays lot of error messages (I don't understand what they are), and finally says 'segmentation fault'. Other accounts on the system are working fine. I need help..!!

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it

Answer (score 1):

Compiz is very advanced tool and should be used with caution. Otherwise you will face this kind of problem.

**Reset Unity**

Run following in terminal.

```
unity --reset
```

**Reset Unity Launcher icons**

If you want to reset the Unity Launcher icons (dock bar on the left) to their initial state, run the following command:

```
unity --reset-icons
```

**Reset Compiz**

Run following in terminal.

```
sudo gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1
sudo gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/compizconfig-1
```

Logout and Logback in.

Comment: let us know if it worked.

Comment: Did not work in my case

Comment: I deleted all the files starting with a dot (.) on the home folder. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Somehow open a terminal in your x session. I created a file on my desktop called tmp.sh, edited its rights to be executable, entered sleep 100000 in it and then ran it.
2. Run `ccsm` this will open the compiz configuration manager window.
3. Do the opposite of what you did that screwed it up.

Comment: 1.: You can execute the terminal directly, it is located at `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal`.