# How Can I Get Transparent Right Click Menus Back in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, compiz, menu

Before upgrading to 12.04, I was running 11.10. I had a Compiz setting enabled via Ubuntu Tweak. That setting was *'Enable Transparent Menus'*. This option allowed all 'right click menus' to be partially transparent, a feature I have grown fond of.

After upgrading to 12.04, I am *unable to locate this option.* I have installed all of the same packages that were on 11.10, so packages aren't the problem.

I would like to know, where can *I enable this?* And was this feature removed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a way to do this using the [CompizConfig Settings Manager (CCSM)](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/), although it is a bit more complicated.

> ### Warning!
>
> [You can very easily break your desktop using CCSM](https://askubuntu.com/q/80589/18612). Follow these instructions and any other answers recommending CCSM at
> your own risk. If you run into problems, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/17610/18612) for
> instructions on how to restore Unity to working condition.

You can install CCSM by looking for it in the Ubuntu Software Center or by entering in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Once installed, start it up and go into the options for the **Opacity, Brightness and Saturation** plugin. Click the checkbox to the left of it to enable the plugin first, then add a new rule under the **Window specific settings** section of the **Opacity** tab. The "Windows" textbox should contain:

```
Tooltip|Menu|PopupMenu|DropdownMenu
```

...and the "Window values" slider should be set to 90 (recommended). This value can be tweaked to your taste.

For more detailed information and screenshots, see my (<s>[source](http://technostripe.com/make-menus-transparent-with-compiz/)</s><sup>Expired domain</sup>).

Comment: +1 for the warning, CCSM is very powerful, but very easy to break

Comment: works in 14.04 too