# Unable to re-install compizconfig-settings-manager

Tags: compiz, held-packages

While attempting to fix a problem with compiz settings manager, I got an idea from someone to purge compiz - *`sudo apt-get purge compiz`*. The compiz core packages are still intact however, the gui `compizconfig-settings-manager` is deleted and missing from synaptic. If I try to install through terminal I get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
compizconfig-settings-manager:i386 :

Depends: python-compizconfig:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: python-gtk2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

Any suggestions or insight is appreciated.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get -f install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, an essential package `compiz` is removed from your system. Unity depends on compiz package. You said that, compizconfig-settings-manager also get removed, it is normal, because "compizconfig-settings-manager" requires compiz, which is removed by the command.

I'd like to suggest to disable all the 3rd party PPAs, and enable all the official Ubuntu repository *(including proposed)*. Then run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install compiz` commands. Also run `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager` to get the useful software. *You should [read this first](https://askubuntu.com/q/80589/61218) though.

[Click this link](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=how%20to%20enable%20repository) to get useful questions and answers about enabling various repository.

If your problem does not solved with the above procedure, I assume that, You have installed `compiz` from a 3rd party PPA, which is not supported officially. If this is indeed the case, then I'd suggest to enable that PPA first, then run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install compiz`.

Hope this helps!