# Unity launcher fails to auto-hide after 15 minutes of use

Tags: unity, launcher

My Unity launcher is set to Auto-hide and hides  however, about 15 minutes into using it, it just stops hiding and sits on top of my windows.

I see here many are experiencing a problem with the launcher **not coming back** from auto-hide, (this is the opposite of my issue) as mine just stops auto-hiding

Is there a way I can reset the unity launcher so I can go back to auto-hide working again?

I prefer a  permanent solution, as it happens every time I use it.

Comment: Welcome Insomnia, to kick of the process of elimination, Do you have CCSM installed?  If so you might find some clues to your issues in the answers in this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it (while your waiting for an answer)

Comment: @StephenMyall no I actually dont have it. My system right now is still all the default programs that came with the 12.04 disc from the .iso desktop image. I have yet to install anything else so far. But I have logged out, and into Windows 7 (dual boot) at least 10-15 times now, and each time its happened. So its not just not a completely 'new' install, but its still has all the default programs and nothing more.  Thanks Stephen for the welcome. I am surprised about your answer though, every other answer relevant to this suggest to install CompizConfig manager surprisingly.

Comment: The additional information provided is helpful. Will continue to look at it

Comment: @StephenMyall Thanks for the help Stephen. Id like to mention another issue I am now having that is relevant to the main topic. I noticed that Thunderbird, and the Terminal is not 'registering' as open on the unity launcher. I click the terminal icon to open the already opened terminal session, and it just opens another each time I click. Never showing the terminal being open. Same with Thunderbird. But luckily Thunderbird isn't as bad, and just doesn't show its open, but doesn't open another. Thunderbird and Terminal are the only things I have added to the launcher, so that may be part of it.