# Installing live wallpapers Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, compiz, desktop-background

How can I use live wall papers with Ubuntu 12.04 like android

Answer (score 3):

First install compiz settings manager from software center.

Then add this ppa

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fyrmir/compiz-plugins && sudo apt-get update
```

And install the plug in

```
sudo apt-get install  compiz-plugins-livewallpapers
```

Now open compiz config that you downloaded earlier (look in dash home or `ccsm` in terminal)

Then on the left you will see "live wallpapers" click it and choose the one you want, easy. (you must press super {windows}key and f4 to activate / de activate the wallpapers)

NOTE : I think you get 3 wallpapers with the package but there is more at [gnome-look.org](http://gnome-look.org/?xsection=home)

Enjoy folks this is really cool :)

Comment: Some reading material for you, something to keep in mind  http://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it

Comment: Yes you have a valid point. I generally have no problems with ccsm but this is recommended reading for any one not familiar with compiz. If you mess with settings you do not understand you may break your Ubuntu.