# How to Alt-Tab switch between windows without popup?

Tags: 12.04, unity, compiz, window-manager

Sometimes I'd like to switch between windows using Alt-Tab or similar shortcut without the popup (showing window thumbnails). Is it possible in 12.04? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A quick look at the CompizConfig Settings Manager (CCSM) suggests this is not possible for the default Unity switcher. I don't see any settings there related to time-out, so I'm afraid the simple answer is "no", unless someone can tell you about hidden settings somewhere.

What you could do is switch to an alternative switcher. In CCSM you can disable the Unity switcher and replace it with e.g. the `Static Application Switcher`. That one allows you to set the `Popup Window Delay` which enables you to hide the window list for the first X seconds. I've left it at the default value of `0.2`, which is high enough for the popup not to show up if I know where the window I want is, but low enough to show the popup if I don't know where to find that window.

Just keep in mind that this alternative switcher doesn't look as pretty as the default switcher. However, it does offer a wealth of other functions (for example, this one allows you to click the window you want to switch to). Also remember that CCSM can be a dangerous programme and might break Compiz if you select the wrong window.

If you want I could upload a screenshot, just let me know :)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I am aware of CCSM, but I am reluctant to use it as it is not recommended http://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it

Comment: Can't blame you for that, I've messed up my configuration a few times as well using CCSM :)
I can't make any promises, but if you make sure you know how to recover it (perhaps `rm ~/.compiz-1`, or `unity --reset`, Google around a bit) you should be quite safe. Worst case scenario you need to reconfigure your Unity. Note that you can save your Compiz configuration from CCSM.

I fear that if you want to customise your Ubuntu machine a bit, there's often no way around CCSM. At least not yet.

Comment: Anyone reading the above: In Ubuntu 12.10 the --reset argument has been deprecated. An excellent answer explaining how you can now reset your configuration is available from:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration