# How do I disable visual effects in Ubuntu 12.04.1?

Tags: compiz, macosx

So I finally managed to install Ubuntu 12.04.1 on my G5 iMac but I don't want any fancy visual effects. How do I disable those? My user logs in automatically and I can't find anything in System Settings, there is no visual effects tab inside the appearance applet.

I would like to keep the nice Unity shell but just disable visual effects so that the Quartz part of my video card doesn't get used.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, you might want to try Unity 2D; just select it when logging in. You will have no 3D desktop, but you will keep the HUD and other Unity goodies.

Second solution is to install the Compiz Settings Manager, known as ccsm, and tune it to your heart's content. You will still be using Compiz, but you can switch off annoying eye-candies, if that is what you want.

There is no way of keeping Unity 3D without Compiz, because it is a Compiz plugin.

Comment: Be careful, though, because CCSM is notorious for breaking your system: http://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it

Comment: Yup, the Ubuntu 2D thing did the trick. Thank!

Comment: CCSM should be avoided.  See here for alternatives: http://askubuntu.com/q/205206/18665