# Which alternative to using CCSM (Compiz Config Settings Manager)

Tags: software-recommendation, compiz

The warning "[What are some of the issues with ccsm and why should I not use it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it)" is referenced in a lot of answers. But no alternative to it is proposed anywhere.

What are the alternatives ?

In 12.10, thinks seems to span between gconf and dconf (and maybe elsewhere ?). I was not able to find the real place to set focus follow mouse for example (metacity gconf option seems to do nothing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually a handful of alternatives to CCSM. Here's a quick rundown:

**Current:**

- [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/)

  - Been around since 2007. [Development briefly stopped in 2012](http://blog.ubuntu-tweak.com/2012/10/19/the-development-of-ubuntu-tweak-is-stopped.html), but it's been around the longest and [it's still being actively developed](https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak). Supports Ubuntu 8.04 to the latest version (currently 14.04). Download it directly from the [Ubuntu Tweak website](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) to install.
- [Unity Tweak Tool](https://launchpad.net/unity-tweak-tool)

  - New since 2013, [still being actively developed](https://code.launchpad.net/unity-tweak-tool). For some reason it's the only one in the official repositories. To install (for 13.04+):

    ```
    sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
    ```

**Past:**

- [MyUnity](http://www.uielinux.org/myunity/)

  - Appeared in 2011, [development stopped in 2012](https://code.launchpad.net/myunity). Supported Ubuntu 11.04 - 12.04.
- [Unsettings](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/unsettings/)

  - Appeared in 2012, [development stopped in 2013](https://code.launchpad.net/unsettings). Supported Ubuntu 11.10 - 13.04.

Answer (score 5):

Most of the settings in CCSM can be altered/changed using `gsettings` command. `dconf-editor` is a graphical alternative to it also. But both of them requires some knowledge about the backend system.

MyUnity and Ubuntu tweak was great (limited), but I heard they get removed from 12.10.

- Here is the [manual page for gsettings](http://www.manpagez.com/html/gio/gio-2.28.6/gsettings-tool.php)

  For example, to change the font from Ubuntu 11 size to Ubuntu 10 size, you would execute this command:

  ```
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface font-name 'Ubuntu 10'
  ```
- You can install `dconf-editor` with the command `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`

**Update: Ubuntu tweak is back now!! That is a great news actually. So happy tweaking !**

Comment: Ubuntu-Tweak is back.