# How do I disable the minimization effect?

Tags: unity, compiz

In Ubuntu 12.10 there has been a minimize effect added to the system.

The minimize effect was not present in previous version of Ubuntu.

The effect makes things seem slow.

How can I disable it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open the app called CompizConfig Settings Manager. Click [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/) to install it, if you haven't already.

Then disable the "Animations" effect. You can access this setting quickly if you type "Animations" in the search field of CompizConfig Settings Manager.

Pro-tip: the app also permits you to increase the speed of the animation !

- [What are some of the issues with CCSM and why would I want to avoid it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it)

Comment: This did not work it still slow looking

Comment: Found it disable Animation removes it.
your answer got me close to it.

Comment: That effect is supposed to speed up after 50-100 times,i'm not sure of the exact amount of times until it speeds up but is deliberatly slow at first.I can see many finding that rather annoying

Answer (score 2):

Another way to speed up the minimization animation if by using the app called "Dconf Editor".

The whole procedure to do so has been thoroughly described [on OMG! Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/10/how-to-speed-up-ubuntu-12-10-minimize-animation).

Comment: I looked at those instructions - they're not particularly user friendly. :/