# Compiz does not work well

Tags: 12.04, unity, ati, compiz

Well this is the first time I'm with Ubuntu. The problem is that after installing Compiz and extras, I can install the cube and some other elements. But there are problems with: **3d windows**, **Paint fire**, and **Water effect**.

**3d windows** makes the cube unstable and the window effects do not work as the cube disappears.

**Paint fire** and **Water effect** simply do not work.

After reading and reading, I installed the proprietary drivers and checked 3D acceleration; everything is correct, but those Compiz effects still do not work.

The card is an AMD ATI Radeon HD 7400

```
~$ glxinfo | grep direct 
direct rendering: Yes
    GL_AMD_multi_draw_indirect, GL_AMD_name_gen_delete, 
    GL_ARB_draw_indirect, GL_ARB_draw_instanced, 
    GL_EXT_copy_buffer, GL_EXT_copy_texture, GL_EXT_direct_state_access,
```

I don't know what to do... I don'w know if there is some incompatibility with Unity, but I've seen videos in which Compiz is working perfectly well.

Thanks for the help, and if you need to know anything please ask.

---

**Original post**

Bueno, es la primera vez que estoy con Ubuntu. El problema es que después de instalar Compiz y los extras, puedo instalar el cubo y algunos otros elementos. Pero el problema viene en las siguientes tareas: **3d windows**, **Paint fire** y **Water effect**.

**3d windows** hace que el cubo no sea nada estable y no se llega a ver bien el efecto de las ventanas en 3d ya que el cubo desaparece.

**Paint fire** y **Water effect** directamente no funcionan.

Despues de leer y leer he instalado los *drivers* privativos y comprobado la aceleración 3d: todo está correcto, pero aun así Compiz no funciona.

La tarjeta es una ATI AMD Radeon HD 7400

```
~$ glxinfo | grep direct 
direct rendering: Yes
    GL_AMD_multi_draw_indirect, GL_AMD_name_gen_delete, 
    GL_ARB_draw_indirect, GL_ARB_draw_instanced, 
    GL_EXT_copy_buffer, GL_EXT_copy_texture, GL_EXT_direct_state_access,
```

No sé qué hacer... No sé si es por una incopatibilidad con Unity, pero hay vídeos en los cuales se ve Compiz funcionando perfectamente.

Gracias por la ayuda y si necesitan saber cualquier cosa pregunten tranquilamente.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a AskUbuntu. Este sitio funciona en idioma inglés, por lo que será importante que haga un esfuerzo de traducir su pregunta a ese idioma, pero si no puede hacerlo, trate de que la pregunta original sea clara.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check "[What are some of the issues with Compiz Config Settings Manager (CCSM) and why would I want to avoid it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-would-i-want-to-avoid-it)" to learn more about what works and what doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the paint fire and water effects have been broken for some time now. I'm not sure, but it is possible that the 3d windows effect is also broken.