# upgrade 16.04 > 16.04.1 = unable to move windows (even though move windows is checked in ccsm) and other gui issues

Tags: unity, 16.04, virtualbox

Very new ubuntu user here.

I just updated ubuntu (running on virtualbox on windows) from 16.04 to 16.04.1.

When I rebooted my vm - all of the menus, panels, minimise/maximise/close elements were not visible. I have since managed to get the menus to appear as per screenshot below. I am able to right-click and open a terminal session and run programs (as per pgadmin3 running on the right-hand side of the desktop). If I right-click and open an additional terminal session, it is superimposed on the first, and I cannot `alt-tab` or `alt-~` to any other terminal session.

[image]

In addition, I am unable to move windows, yet `move windows` is checked in ccsm.

I have tried the top-rated answers for the following questions without success:

- [No panels or menus after upgrading to 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468204/no-panels-or-menus-after-upgrading-to-14-04)
- [Ubuntu 16.04 no menu bar or launcher - help!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761035/ubuntu-16-04-no-menu-bar-or-launcher-help)
- [Close/minimize/maximize button not appearing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294938/close-minimize-maximize-button-not-appearing)
- [How can I always show the close, minimise & maximise buttons into their own windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64831/how-can-i-always-show-the-close-minimise-maximise-buttons-into-their-own-wind)
- [Ubuntu 12.04 Missing Close, Minimize and Maximize Button after Update and Upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/418425/ubuntu-12-04-missing-close-minimize-and-maximize-button-after-update-and-upgrad)
- [Unity missing? Can't see top or side panels](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204428/unity-missing-cant-see-top-or-side-panels?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Application's menu missing from menu bar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762137/applications-menu-missing-from-menu-bar)
- [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)
- [Unity Launcher and Top Panel disappeared in 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475296/unity-launcher-and-top-panel-disappeared-in-14-04)

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Is `Desktop Wall` checked in CCSM ?

Comment: no - should it be?

Comment: Yes. Check it. See if it allows you move windows

Comment: checked it, couldn't move windows. rebooted, checked that it was still checked (it was) couldn't move windows :-/

Comment: See my screenshot. http://imgur.com/a/Z9ssR  Typically issues with moving windows or workspaces come from compiz plugins not being checked. Unity plugin is the most important one - without it there's no decorations or launcher . It doesn't show in the main panel, but if you click on it, the right panel has option for checking it.

Comment: thanks for uploading that - I've made sure that unity is checked (it wasn't) and checked viewport switcher (because it was checked in the screenshot you added) (it wasn't checked on my machine). Since making these changes - I've rebooted - still the same issues.

Comment: How about any of these ? http://imgur.com/a/DS3O3

Comment: place and resize were unchecked (now checked - rebooted - no effect). Maximumize is not even there to check...

Comment: Very odd.  I don't have many more ideas. Let me know if no-one finds a solution in a few days, ok ?

Comment: sure thing, thanks for your help! one last question - I've found out that metacity is not installed - does this matter?

Comment: That shouldn't matter. IIRC metacity is another window manager, just like compiz

Comment: yeah - you are correct - just finished doing some reading about it

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable the ccsm "window decoration" as it conflicts with the newest unity plugin.

Also, you need to enable the unity plugin in ccsm.

When using unity, all you need to do is click and drag down from the top panel to grab a window to move it.

I have found that alt button1 is a good option for the move plugin that works. Just press alt and hold down left click to move a window.

[image]

[image]

Comment: window decoration is (was already) disabled. Unity is currently selected as the profile for ccsm. I'll do some googling now to work out how to find out if it is enabled or not.

Comment: @Sean In 16.04 there is a unity plugin. Enable this plugin.

Comment: sorry for this - but to clarify - if unity is running - does this mean that it is enabled? (please see my screenshot in the question) On a separate note, I can't move the windows at all (either click-hold or using alt...)

Comment: @Sean No, I don't think so. I believe compiz is running and unity is simply a compiz plugin. I have added some photos. Also, disable gnome compatibility if it is enabled.

Comment: ah, thanks for adding those - unity wasn't enabled (I swear that it was before, but regardless - it definitely is now). I've since rebooted to no avail.

Comment: Unity in reality is nothing more but a compiz plugin. Compiz is the actual window manager. If it doesn't have Unity enabled , windows wont have decorations or any shortcuts for moving, alt-tabing, no workspaces either. Time to time compiz crashes ( that just happens for whatever reason ) and i found over and over that you need Unity plugin checked. That's 99% of cases

Comment: gnome compatibility is unchecked.

Comment: @Sean Take a look here, and you may have to install the dconf-editor http://askubuntu.com/a/290376/167115

Comment: thanks for the link. I had tried that before, but I just tried it again (after the changes that I've made following your suggestions) - and it still hasn't changed the situation :-/

Comment: @Sean Make sure 3d acceleration is enabled in your virtual machine options.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem yesterday after updating. I haven't been able to fix it, but I figured out a way to avoid it, by using i3 as my GUI instead of the the one that comes standard with Ubuntu.  https://i3wm.org/docs/repositories.html

Comment: okay cool. I did install mate (to see if the issue went away) - but it didn't make a difference. I might try i3 and see if that is any different :-)

Answer (score 0):

Uninformed Ubuntu user.
The behaviour of Gnome windows changed after I messed up with the BIOS, setting up for UEFI and back for non-UEFI BIOS.

As a result, all new windows from Gnome opened too towards the left and too towards the top. And I could only move/resize windows with the ALT+move trick (for the first time; after I ALT+moved the window, the behavior was normal). Windows opening in LibreOfficee (for example) behaved correctly.

After messing up for a while trying the recipes from this thread (without success) and others, I found the solution by opening CCSM from terminal -> Window Management -> Place windows -> General (tab) > uncheck "Workarounds" (+ all other suggestions from this thread)
Hope this can be helpful

Pablo

Answer (score 0):

Enabling `Place Windows` plugin on CompizConfig Settings Manager did a trick for me.

BTW. I also have enabled `Move Window` and disabled `Workarounds`

And thank you for remebering abount `Alt + Left Mouse` for move the window!