# How does one detect when the currently visible workspace is switched?

Tags: 14.10, workspaces, workspace-switcher

I'm using Ubuntu 14.10 and would like to be able to have different screen resolutions on different workspaces. I was thinking of writing a script/daemon that calls `xrandr` whenever it detects a switch – the question is, how does one detect a change?

Comment: That script exists already: http://askubuntu.com/questions/587077/different-screen-resolutions-for-each-work-space/587262#587262

Comment: @JacobVijm thanks, I had been googling for solutions, but didn't see that one. wmctrl is exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

The [question marked as providing an answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/587077/different-screen-resolutions-for-each-work-space) does indeed provide an ample solution to my specific problem, but is a slightly narrower question. In the interests of the community, I shall summarise the parts relevant to this broader question, and in a more general manner:

The tool one requires is `wmctrl` (installable through `apt-get install wmctrl`). `wmctrl -d` gives information about the current desktop, including (DG) the total size of the virtual desktop (i.e. the combined size of all workspaces) and (VP) the absolute position of the top-left corner of the current workspace relative to the virtual desktop. The column of the currently active workspace can be determined by dividing the x-coord of VP by the horizontal part of the current screen resolution. The row of the current workspace can be calculated using the y-coord of VP and the vertical part of the current resolution. To detect a switch, one should use a while loop to constantly check the row and column of the current workspace and determine if it has changed / meets a certain test.