# How to have a different background for each workspace in MATE

Tags: workspaces, mate, desktop-background

I know this has been answered before but that solution doesn't work on Ubuntu MATE. Anyway to achieve this on MATE?

Output of `wmctrl -d`:

```
$ wmctrl -d
0  * DG: 1366x768  VP: 0,0  WA: 0,25 1366x719  Workspace 1
1  - DG: 1366x768  VP: N/A  WA: 0,25 1366x719  Workspace 2
2  - DG: 1366x768  VP: N/A  WA: 0,25 1366x719  Workspace 3
3  - DG: 1366x768  VP: N/A  WA: 0,25 1366x719  Workspace 4
```

Output of $ `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION`:

```
$ echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
mate
```

Original solution that I tried and that didn't work for me:
 [Is it possible to have a different background for each workspace?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75998/is-it-possible-to-have-a-different-background-for-each-workspace)

Comment: Please add a link to the solution that doesn't work in order to show what you tried.

Comment: I could edit this one https://askubuntu.com/questions/305468/multiple-workspace-wallpapers-without-using-ccsm/560734#560734 (https://launchpad.net/~vlijm/+archive/ubuntu/wswitcher) to work with mate, but please add the output of `wmctrl -d`  to your question, to make sure how mate handles workspaces (I don't run Mate). Currently, the application works for Unity and Budgie.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I have added the output

Comment: @simlev I added the link

Comment: Cool! that means the code just needs a tiny edit. I forgot one thing: could you also post the *exact* output of  `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION`?

Comment: I've added it! @JacobVlijm

Comment: Thanks! tomorrow or day after tomorrow, I will push an update, will ping you if I do :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm Thank you so much! I've been trying to get this to work for about 2 weeks and now that you can provide a solution, just make me happy! :)

Comment: waitwait, please test if the command `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri` has a valid output.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I tried that and it spat out this link `'file:///usr/share/backgrounds/gnome/adwaita-timed.xml'` 
I tried to open the link and it said "No such directory". Not sure if that's a valid or invalid output

Comment: Well, looks like the key exists :). Will post later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I could not test it, due to the fact that I don't have Mate avaialble atm, looking at the output of `wmctrl -d`, and given the fact that wallpapers on Mate are obviously set with the same `gsettings` command, I see no reason why it should not work.

#### The script

The script below is an edited version of [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/560734/72216), and kind of an exerpt of the one [I pushed to Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~vlijm/+archive/ubuntu/wswitcher). As it is, that one won't work for Mate, since I added a session-check in that one, for either Unity or Budgie.

If you can confirm the script below works on Mate, I'll probably edit the ppa version to include Mate.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess    
import os
import time

try:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(os.environ["HOME"], ".config/wswitcher"))
except FileExistsError:
    pass

workspace_data = os.environ["HOME"]+"/.config/wswitcher/wallpaper_data_"
key = [
    "gsettings get ",
    "gsettings set ",
    "org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri",
    ]

def getwall():
    return subprocess.check_output(
        ["/bin/bash", "-c", key[0]+key[2]]
        ).decode("utf-8").strip()

def get_res():
    # get resolution
    xr = subprocess.check_output(["xrandr"]).decode("utf-8").split()
    pos = xr.index("current")
    return [int(xr[pos+1]), int(xr[pos+3].replace(",", "") )]

def current_ws():
    # get the current workspace
    wsdata = subprocess.check_output(["wmctrl", "-d"]).decode("utf-8").splitlines()
    return [l.split()[0] for l in wsdata if "*" in l][0]

def wswitcher(curr_ws1, currwall1):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        currwall2 = getwall()
        curr_ws2 = current_ws()
        datafile = workspace_data+curr_ws2
        if curr_ws2 == curr_ws1:
            if currwall2 != currwall1:
                open(datafile, "wt").write(currwall2)
        else:
            if not os.path.exists(datafile):
                open(datafile, "wt").write(currwall2)
            else:
                curr_set = open(datafile).read()
                command = key[1]+key[2]+' "'+str(curr_set)+'"'
                subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", command])
        curr_ws1 = curr_ws2
        currwall1 = getwall()

curr_ws1 = current_ws(); currwall1 = getwall()
wswitcher(curr_ws1, currwall1)
```

#### How to use

1. Copy the script into an empty file
2. Save it as `wallswitcher.py`
3. Test- run it by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/wallswitcher.py
   ```
4. Then simply start setting up your wallpapers as demonstrated [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/05/set-different-wallpapers-for-each.html).
5. If all works fine, add it to Startup Applications:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 10 && /path/to/wallswitcher.py
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed by Jacob Vlijm works fine on my Mate, provided that I change `org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri` to `org.mate.background picture-filename` in the script (information found [here](http://wiki.mate-desktop.org/mate-backgrounds)).