# How to play Race The Sun in full screen 12.04 Unity

Tags: unity, compiz, fullscreen

I have been playing "RaceTheSun" on Ubuntu 12.04 using Unity-3D(desktop) with Compiz.

However, It seems It does not have an option to go full screen, neither in the game options or on the window controls.

[image]

I have read this forum post about changing Unity3d(game engine) settings from command line:
http://flippfly.com/forum/beta-testers-1/linux-fullscreen-and-general-game-issues/

However this seems only to resize the window size, the window still has decoration and the launcher/top-bar still show over the application.

Is there a way around this, to play the game in full screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Developer here!

Just thought I'd let you know, that in the latest release of Race The Sun (1.1), there is an in-game option to enable full-screen. If you launch the game it should direct you to the download page.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Awesome work! Can you add a "WM_CLASS" to the window as well - it is used to make a better launcher in Ubuntu - I made a simple launcher assuming you extract to Documents, http://ubuntuone.com/2d5Pi8zy31acLYh8ws7oLZ this also adds links to the website on rightclick on the launcher, (also uses the icon high-quality) Just need the program to define WM_CLASS to merge the icons when the game is launched.

Comment: Great to see the game devs getting involved with the site.

Answer (score 1):

### For old 1.02 Version

To play Race The Sun in full screen you can change some settings with `compiz` to achieve this.

1. Install **compizconfig-settings-manager** (please note: [What are some of the issues with CCSM and why would I want to avoid it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-would-i-want-to-avoid-it) Basically Be Careful) :

   Type in terminal: `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
2. Open compizconfig-settings-manager from dash:
   [image]
3. Go to → Window Managment → Window Rules → Check "Enable Window Rules"
   [image]
4. Enter `title=RaceTheSun` into the field: **Fullscreen**  (since it seems RaceTheSun does not use WM_CLASS we rely on the title field)
   [image]
5. Exit out, launch RaceTheSun, Enjoy!