# How to disable unity window open/close animation? (No third party software)

Tags: unity, display, window, animations

I am wondering how I can disable the maximize/minimize animation for ubuntu 13.10. I know there are other questions like this, but they are either directed to different ubuntu types, (Kubuntu, etc) or they are recommending third party software (Unity Tweak Tool).

I would like to disable this with a built in option, if possible. If not, what would be the best application to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best option might be to use the Compizconfig Settings Manager:

```
sudo apt-get install compiz compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-fusion-plugins-extra compiz-fusion-plugins-main compiz-plugins
```

You should then be able to open Compiz through the dash by searching for "ccsm".

Once it's open, go to "animations" and you should be able to find the options to disable things there.

Comment: Is this better than Unity Tweak Tool?

Comment: @Trevor no its not. You could easily break your system with CCSM: http://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-would-i-want-to-avoid-it/80590#80590

Comment: I agree: you have to be very careful with CCSM. Unity Tweak Tool is much safer and I would use that over CCSM in situations which it would suffice.