# How to turn off window refreshing during resizing

Tags: unity, compiz, window, resize

I have noticed that ever since upgrade to 14.04, when working with R, resizing a window triggers thousands of redrawing requests. This is able to kill off my session completely if the redrawing takes much time, as is the case with many complex statistical plots.

Is it possible to resize windows in current Unity using a wireframe only?

Comment: Good question! A potential temporary solution would be to resize the window by its id from terminal (`wmctrl` maybe)? Slow and ugly and error-trial like, but it would work until another solution is found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To control how the window manager (compiz) controls resizing requires a bit of poking around in the various gsettings values.

In particular there is the resize compiz plugin with a mode parameter which you can fiddle with.

By default it is set to "0" which is "Normal" and equates to whole window resizing

```
gsettings set org.compiz.resize:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/resize/ mode 0
```

A value of "1" is enough to stop whole window resizing and switch to displaying a frame

```
gsettings set org.compiz.resize:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/resize/ mode 1
```

A value of "2" displays a frame with a blur of the window border

```
gsettings set org.compiz.resize:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/resize/ mode 2
```

A value of "3" shrinks the window during resizing:

```
gsettings set org.compiz.resize:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/resize/ mode 3
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. One can change the value also using compiz settings manager, under "resize plugin" / "default resize mode".

Comment: yep - however we tend to try not to give answers any more using ccsm for this reason: http://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-would-i-want-to-avoid-it

Comment: Well, yeah, that is true, the arguments in that response are totally valid, but this answer is from 2011 and this migration still did not happen -- I still wouldn't know how to make my desktop usable w/o CCSM. My guess is that CCSM is not going away anywhere soon, and when it does, I will have to follow it.