# Using the CCSM, is there a way to run Desktop Cube smoothly with Unity Desktop Manager?

Tags: unity, 15.10, ccsm

I have tried several times in UBUNTU 15.10 to run the cool looking eye candy option of the Desktop Cube with small to catastrophic failures. Any advice?

buxtor

Answer (score 1):

CCSM has been dangerous now for a very long time.

[See this question about problems with CCSM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-would-i-want-to-avoid-it/80590#80590)

I cannot recommend it at all.

Generally the features it provided were moved to more pertinent locations with the advent of Unity, and in some cases nixed. Unity was developed in a completely different mantra - I would not expect smooth sailing, and many, many conflicts.

I'm quite surprised it's still available these days.  I remember running Eve Online fondly with desktop cube running!

(Here's my Ubuntu 9.04 +Compiz +Eve Online video from 2009!) 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4tvJssnzNhw

For now, there isn't really an alternative.

Kind Regards

Comment: Sure, http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/01/should-ccsm-be-purged-from-the-ubuntu-repos

http://askubuntu.com/a/80590/24781

https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-desktop/2012-January/003612.html

Hope this helps to clarify my opinion.

Do you believe these links as relevant and worth posting in my answer?

It's a difficult topic really, there is no "answer" as everything is opinion.

Kind Regards

Comment: No problem :)  Once burned!